# I need to create a stopping condition for my program

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a program that highlights all the words between a start and end point and loops through the extract to find the same conditions. Program works well, except it does not stop looping. I have to break the running program to stop it. can someone please help me write up a condition that says if the end is reached and the start and end condition don't to exist, to stop the program.

```
Sub SomeSub1()

Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
Dim Find1stRange As range, FindEndRange As range
Dim DelRange As range, DelStartRange As range, DelEndRange As range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Setting up the Ranges
Set Find1stRange = ActiveDocument.range
Set FindEndRange = ActiveDocument.range
Set DelRange = ActiveDocument.range

'Set your Start and End Find words here to cleanup the script
StartWord = "From: Yussuf Ismail"
EndWord = "Kind regards"

'Starting the Find First Word
With Find1stRange.Find
    .Text = StartWord
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

    'Execute the Find
    Do While .Execute
        'If Found then do extra script
        If .Found = True Then
            'Setting the Found range to the DelStartRange
            Set DelStartRange = Find1stRange
            'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
            DelStartRange.Select

            'Setting the FindEndRange up for the remainder of the document form the end of the StartWord
            FindEndRange.Start = DelStartRange.End
            FindEndRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

            'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
            FindEndRange.Select


            'Setting the Find to look for the End Word
            With FindEndRange.Find
                .Text = EndWord
                .Execute

                'If Found then do extra script
                If .Found = True Then
                    'Setting the Found range to the DelEndRange
                    Set DelEndRange = FindEndRange

                    'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
                    DelEndRange.Select

                End If

            End With

            'Selecting the delete range
            DelRange.Start = DelStartRange.Start
            DelRange.End = DelEndRange.End
            'Having these Selections during testing is benificial to test your script
            DelRange.Select
DelRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
            'Remove comment to actually delete




        End If      'Ending the If Find1stRange .Found = True
    Loop        'Ending the Do While .Execute Loop
End With    'Ending the Find1stRange.Find With Statement


End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend you use a Boolean variable to track whether .Execute was successful. As it is, the "Do" is testing the original .Execute, not the one that is performed within the loop. If you test a Boolean value that is set to .Execute each time that should help. Same thing where you have If .Found - use the same boolean variable, that's more reliable.

Comment: Nice piece of code @jaydub  (hahah thought it looked familiar).

Answer (score 0):

It keeps on going because of the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

This will remove the "Search has reached the end of the document. Do you want to continue searching at the beginning?" message.

If you remove the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` then it will stop at the end of the document and that message will pop up.

Also change the following in the initial `Find`:

```
.Wrap = wdFindAsk
```

To

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

this will then not ask the question and just stop the `Find`.